# Can I hide Google Drive files/folders for specific emails or IPs that are open to general public (or anyone with link)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api, google-workspace-add-ons

Is there any way to use the drive api to hide certain files or folders for specific emails of IP addresses? I'm trying to build additional flexibility beyond the user access controls that google offers since I won't know all the users emails (as to just invite them directly) but also want the ability to block others.

The two options I've been able to figure out so far:

1. Use the drive api and build a custom UI that users would access the file list (and set file permissions for anyone with link, however this method couldn't stop someone from distributing the link to people on the blacklist)
2. Put scripts on certain files directly, such as sheets, that would hide the sheets depending on the user's email

Neither one is ideal. Is there any straightforward way to check a user's IP/email then just hide certain folders/files? Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: IP would be hard, but why not just add emails to list of viewers?

Comment: I do not know emails of all of the users (and some who would like to remain anonymous) so I'd like to have the ability to have as open to public or accessible with a link but also have the ability to block certain users for accessing. Is there a way to password protect files or folders perhaps as an alternative?

Comment: I don't see how that would work. If a@gmail.com is blocked, the blocked user would simply logout of his email address and access the ui as a anonymous user. As to ips, vpns and proxies are a real problem. I mean, even the logic part itself is amiss here. Having said,  you may build something like that, if the ui doesn't just list the files, but also provides the viewer: For eg, if sheets file is shared, the ui would take the data and convert it into a html table and show the html table. The end user wouldn't have direct access to the file's id or the file itself.